# Microblogging engine in Java

Tags: java, microblogging

Is anybody aware of any open source Twitter/Identica-like microblogging engines written in Java? My basic requirements are that users should be able to

1. Write short comments on some entities in the web application
2. Customize privacy features, like "do not show name/email"
3. Like/dislike comments

and optionally, track user locations.

The ones I've found so far were written in ASP.net (Yonkly), PHP (StatusNet, Floopo, Jisko) or Python (Jaiku).

Comment: so you want to create the next twitter with no effort? :)

Comment: (good question, though - it's nice to know what solutions exist)

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the [**Atmosphere Framework**](http://atmosphere.java.net/) with its [JQuery plugin](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2010/06/15/using-atmospheres-jquery-plug-in-to-build-applicationsupporting-both-websocket-and-comet/) to implement Comet techniques.

Answer (score 1):

It's a few years after the question, granted. I thought it might not hurt to add a comment, though, here in the knowledge web.

Though it's not *per se* a matter of conventional microblogging, but [Apache Roller](http://roller.apache.org/)  provides a conventional blogging framework and API, in Java - in a sort of *superset* of patterns in microblogging. FYI, documentation for Roller 5.0.1 is [here](http://www.apache.org/dist/roller/roller-5/v5.0.1/docs/) - there may've been a bad link, at the site...

As far as measuring "Like" feedback, there are services such as [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/), such that one could integrate with Roller, at the presentation level - perhaps, using [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) or [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/), at that same application level. Granted, it's not a closely integrated feedback system that would make for - may not provide a lot of close integration between the content presentation and the visitor feedback components, if one's using a local API for the content management and social service like ShareThis for the content feedback - but ShareThis, in particular, does integrate with popular social networking services, and it's available. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another "years later" answer, but I had the same issue and created a service around it, http://www.collabinate.com.  I would be interested to know if it would meet the needs of your use case.